# Parsing JSON in PHP with a prepend of sorts

Tags: php, json

if my JSON data is coming back as this:

```
{"errorCodes":[0]}resultArray=[{....}]
```

how do I grab the resultArray as the actual JSON string and ignore the rest?

and why would I need errorCodes in front of it?

Comment: Why are you getting this kind of broken data in the first place? Is fixing the source out of the question?

Comment: it is out of the question, unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use string manipulation to get rid of everything up through `resultArray=` and then decode with `json_decode()`.

```
$json_raw = '...'; // the raw "JSON" string
$delimiter = 'resultArray=';
$cleaned_json = substr($json_raw, strpos($json_raw,$delimiter) + strlen($delimiter)));
$object = json_decode($cleaned_json);
```